# Statistics data on profile views

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

In careers we have some information about our profile views in terms on number of view over the time. It would be nice and worthwhile to have the chance to drill down and get more information about the location (GEO location) of who viewed your profile.

In addition to this it would be nice to see whether who viewed the profile was interested in the questions/answers posted or not, and (even if not so simple to determine) how much time approximately the user spent on your profile .

To recap it would be nice to have some more statistics(maybe even with some charts) about profile views in Careers .

Comment: I like this idea. Giving more data to the programmers instead of just the recruiters.

Comment: So we can stalk potential employers?

Comment: No, it is just out of curiosity. It is interesting to know if people are viewing your profile from UK, or from India for example ... just more information,  don't want to exactly localise companies, just the country would be enough

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing referrers -- did a view come from a web search, a certain Q/A; was I linked to, did someone follow a link I put on my website, etc. etc. I don't care about the number of views, but I'd be curious about how they landed on my profile in the first place. Even a breakdown of hits from StackOverflow, Careers, and Other would be helpful.

Comment: @aleroot If it's just the country you could put a image tracker on your profile. The service I'm using doesn't show referrers, but you could easily just host an invisible image on your server and link it on your profile -- then just check the logs to see referrers and exact IPs. I'd really like to see this implemented, it gives you a better understanding of who you're actually helping. Maybe even extending this to every post you make, not just the profile.

Comment: that view counter too simple, it even counts as a view if you open your profile in a incognito window, at least it should separate anon views from SE users/recruiters views

Comment: looks like this is not a problem anymore http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321935/what-happened-to-seeing-the-number-of-view-a-cv-has-been-accessed