# What happened to seeing the number of views a CV has been accessed?

Tags: discussion, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs

It used to be, up until a couple of days ago, that on the 'edit cv' tab on the jobs section, if the user clicked on settings button, above the print and download buttons the number of times your CV had been viewed total, today, this week and this month... but all of a sudden it stopped showing up... Is this a permanent change?

Comment: Look out for "Stack Overflow Careers Premium", coming soon to a job board near you. See who viewed your profile, extend your reach, and more! Free trials available (credit card required)

Comment: @TZHX We would never do something like that. We're the good people, remember? We would never exclude people without credit cards from being able to proactively engage in expanding their network.

Comment: so bitcoin payments will be accepted? great! :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We removed it because it needs to be re-thought in a world where developer story replaces the Careers CV. It will be specced out and implemented in the near to medium term but I don't know the exact timeframe for that right now.

Comment: Wouldn't the fact that it needs to be (re)implemented be better indicated by [tag:status-planned]?