# Where are the career profile views?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I recall there was a section where you could see how many viewed my profile, and how many of those views were from employers. It used to be somewhere in the red square below.

[image: Red square, views section]

Have I missed anything? Where I can find those kind of statistics?

Comment: See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321935/what-happened-to-seeing-the-number-of-view-a-cv-has-been-accessed) it was removed pending re-implementation mid term.